# Does the feat Point-Blank Shot and similar feats affect ranged touch attack spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, touch-attacks

The confusion with [Point-Blank Shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/point-blank-shot-combat---final) for me comes from this line;

> You get a +1 bonus on attack and damage rolls with *ranged weapons* at ranges of up to 30 feet.

Also, [Precise Shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/precise-shot-combat---final) has a similar line that makes me question it;

> You can shoot or throw *ranged weapons* at an opponent engaged in melee without taking the standard –4 penalty on your attack roll.

All emphasis mine.

I can't determine if that means that only ranged weapons get the bonuses or all ranged attacks.

Would a ranged touch attack get the bonus on attack rolls from either of these feats and similar other ones?  What about the bonus damage from Point-Blank Shot?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes**, ranged attacks from spells are typically considered to be ["weapon-like"](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9oag).  This is definitely true of rays (and almost all ranged touch attack spells are rays) since [from the rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell):

> You aim a ray as if using a ranged weapon

The rules further clarify that rays function as weapons for several other purposes, and the FAQ makes this very explicit:

> **Do rays count as weapons for the purpose of spells and effects that affect weapons?**
>
> Yes [...] rays are treated as weapons, whether they're from spells, a monster ability, a class ability, or some other source
>
> The same rule applies to weapon-like spells such as flame blade, mage's sword, and spiritual weapon--effects that affect weapons work on these spells.

Most ranged touch attacks which aren't rays are things like [acid splash](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/acid-splash) -- spells where you actually throw or aim a physical object.  Those are even more "weapon-like" than rays, so it's probably simplest to say *all* ranged touch attacks work like this.

There's another FAQ that indicates you can take "Weapon Focus (ray)" and the like; strictly speaking I guess those wouldn't apply to orb spells like acid splash.

This is all following the precedent set by 3.5; in *Complete Arcane* it specifies that rays and touch attack spells are "weapon-like" and thus interact with feats in the same way that other weapons do, with a split between ranged/melee type spells.

Comment: …So if ray-wielding wizards haven't been suffering -4 to hit targets engaged in melee, it's time to start!

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, so that applies to ranged touch spells as well as rays?

Comment: It doesn't come straight and say it explicitly, but it's kind of implied.  Pretty much any ranged touch spell is either a ray, or something even *more* similar to a weapon.  ([Orb spells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/acid-splash) and the like.)